# Is it possible to read every book in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, I once read that a guy read *every single book* in Skyrim. I looked this up but could find no real evidence that it was possible. The problem with this as I see it is that books, although sometimes central to the lore and world of Skyrim are easily lost and dropped in favour of other more useful items.

Is it really possible for someone to read all books, or is this just folklore and legend?

Regarding my definition of books; in this case books can include spell tomes, black books, regular books and scrolls.

Comment: ??? It's not that hard, just time consuming (even assuming someone didn't use mods/console commands to give themselves one of every book) there are a finite number of books, many in pre-determined locations, just print out a checklist and read them as you encounter them.

Comment: If you're trying to read all the books, surely they're the most important item.

Comment: Though the real question would be "are there two or more books which can't both be accessed by a single character?"

Comment: "easily lost and dropped" makes it sound as though the question is asking if you can carry all the books in the game, not read them. It should however be clear that you can read a book without picking it up! There's about 470 books and they all weigh 1 unit, so you could even potentially carry them if so wished. Also, the word "book" has at least two meanings, it can mean "literary work" or "a specific item", the OP may be asking if you can read every book *item* in the game - this seems more doubtful because many of them are dynamically placed.

Comment: If definition of book encompasses spell tomes then one potentially unreadable book is the Healing, or Flames, spell tome. The player already starts with the spell so cannot read the book.

Answer (score 5):

Yes

An easy way to accomplish this if you are on PC is to use a console command to take you to a room that contains every single item in the game, including a chest with all of the books in the game.

Use the following command to get to the room:

- coc qasmoke

Use this command to exit the room:

- coc whiterun

If you are on console you will have to do @Nelson method

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

It's relatively simple.  If your goal is to acquire all the books, there are book vendors that you can buy almost everything from, then it is a matter of using online resources to find the ones you are missing.

Comment: I wish to read every book item in the game, not every literary work.

Answer (score 0):

I did this once.  The way I kept to it was headcanon; I'd installed a mod in "Oldrim" (not SE) Skyrim that gave a separate leveling tree for your "profession".  I decided I was going to be a bookworm, since I was a mage, and in my head, every book was my character's favorite item.  I read the books cover to cover, since time in the books increased your "librarian" profession, which in turn gave experience bonuses and IIRC magic bonuses.  Using SkyUI, the inventory showed a little eye next to each book that I had, indeed, read.  This let me track all of the books, notes, etc.

All of that said, remember, mods may add books, which in turn will put you in a situation like real-life where you could *want* to read every book in the world but may not get there.

Being a mage helped quite a bit, as I rapidly got to where I could enchant myself into completely free Destruction spells and used Conjuration to summon weapons. This took a massive amount of weight off of my character so I could just carry the books until my personal goal was complete.